# logical error in this java code, how do i resolve this error?

Tags: java

```
public class DogOwner extends Dog {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Dog dog1 = new Dog ();
    Dog dog2 = new Dog();
    Dog dog3 = new Dog();


    dog1.setLegs(4);
    dog1.setTail(true);
    dog3.setFur(" furry fur");

    System.out.println("this dog has"+ dog1.GetLeg()+"legs");
    System.out.println("does this dog have a tail?"+ dog2.Gettail());
    System.out.println("this dog has"+ dog3.GetFur());
```

}
}

}
}`enter code here`

```
enter code here
public class Dog {
/**  variables**/
    int Legs;
    boolean tail;
    String Fur;

    /** returns the Legs variable (getter)  **/
public int GetLeg(){
    return Legs;

}
/** stores method variable Llgs within variable legs (setter)  **/
    public void setLegs(int legs){
        this.Legs=legs;
    }
    /** returns the tail variable (getter)  **/
    public boolean Gettail(){
        return tail;

    }
    /** stores method variable tail within variable tail (setter)  **/
    public void setTail(boolean tail){
        this.tail=tail;
    }
    /**because the void does not work with String data type, the type String
     *  replaces void to make this code work (Hovercraft Full Of Eels, 2013)
     *  Hovercraft Full Of Eels.2013.why is this code not working in Java?. 
     *  accessed from:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588830/why-is-this-code-not-working-in-java.
     *  stockoverflow.com. [accessed: 14/12/2013]**/

    public String GetFur(){
        return Fur;
    }

    /**stores for the method variable within the parameter variable Fur **/
    public void setFur(String fur){
        this.Fur=fur;

    }

}
```

the output that i wanted was:
this dog has 4 legs,

Does this dog have a tail? True,

this dog has furry fur

the text true should not be text and it should execute what the boolean value is, in this case it should execute true without the use of quoatation mark (hope this makes sense). 
im a beginner at Java and I can't seem to understand fully on how to code in java (or any programming language) using books. I require assistance from someone to fully understand coding. Also please explain how this code was resolved so I can understand the problem and how to resolve these types of problem in the future (hopefully).

thanks in advance.

Comment: it almost seems to work however the only problems are 'this dog has 4 legs' does not seem to execute. The code for this is 'System.out.println("this dog has"+ dog1.GetLeg()+"legs");");'

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put the object in the output string and expect it to know what you mean.

when you add a regular object to a string, it calls its `toString()` method, which you haven't defined and defaults to what looks like a bunch of grable...

Instead, you need to do something like `System.out.println("this dog has"+ dog1.getLegs() +"legs");` and likewise on the others.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be calling the methods, just inserting the objects into the strings - this won't work in a sensible manner most of the time. Try calling the 'get' methods you've implemented.

```
"this dog has " + dog1.GetLegs() + " legs";
"does this dog have a tail? " + dog2.GetTail();
"this dog has " + dog3.GetFur() + " fur";
```

Comment: it works but how do i add spaces to the texts that is displayed?

Comment: The spaces go inside the string literals: "Dogs" vs "Dogs ", the second will have a trailing space. So you could write "this" + " " + "dog" + " " + "has" + " " + dog1.GetLegs() + " " + "legs"

Answer (score 0):

On the lines where you print the information you print the object instead of one of the properties for it. Change the first System.out.println to:

```
System.out.println("this dog has"+ dog1.GetLeg() +"legs");
```

I think you will figure out how to change the other rows :)